# Cannot push my git project to empty repository in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-keys, openssh

I have a problem in my Bitbucket account, which is cannot push my first git project..

I followed the steps of pushing a new git project:

- first command line : `git remote add origin https://said_bous@bitbucket.org/said_bous/landing-page.git`, it works
  right.
- Than the second command: `git push -u origin master`..
  Oops not working and show to me that note: "key_load_public: invalid format"

I think that my private key in openssh format, and my public key correct because Bitbucket accepts it!

I don't know where is the problem...

[image: first command which is works right]

[image: second command which the problem is in it]

Comment: set you key again, you probably made some mistake and its kind of corrupted...

Comment: For future reference, I don't think that screenshots of text ever add anything to a question. Just paste the text (formatted as code).

Comment: you mean the public key?....so i delet it from Bitbucket and i set it from new again..

Comment: λ git push -u origin master

key_load_public: invalid format
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.1' to the list of known hosts.
repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instruction:

```
1. clone project
2. cd to folder
3. git init
4. git add file(s)
5. git commit -a
6. git push - u origin master
```

Comment: in second step you should choose `yes`